# Retrieve info from table with 2 conditions and 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'websitefinal');

//connecting to database and getting the connection object
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Checking if any error occured while connecting
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
} else {
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $id = $_POST['user_id'] ?? '';

    $query = "SELECT UL.* FROM users UL INNER JOIN active_crew L JOIN search SL      ON L.user_id = UL.user_id AND L.search_id = SL.search_id";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $result2 = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        array_push($result2, array(
            'user_id' => $row[0],
            'name_full' => $row[1],
            'Propic' => $row[4]));
    }

    echo json_encode($result2);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve info of users"users table" in the active crew table who are on duty on a specific search "search table" but I'm not getting any info back

user table which I wanna retrieve data from "user_id" primary and foreign key

crew table only have 2 columns search_id and user_id both are foreign key

search table which should have the duty description "search_id" primary and foreign key

key relationship is active for all columns search_id.crew with search_id.search
user_id.crew with user_id.user

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the conditions of each join at the `ON` clause of each `JOIN` and not all of them at the last `ON`:

```
SELECT UL.* 
FROM users UL 
INNER JOIN active_crew L ON L.user_id = UL.user_id 
INNER JOIN search SL ON L.search_id = SL.search_id
```